# Aparecer Imagens

Tags: php

Olá, eu tenho um PHP aqui que "gera" imagens recém hospedadas no jogo em que eu jogo, e queria saber se é possível fazer com que ele gere mais imagens, sem repetir nenhuma, é possível? (é importante que sempre continue o mesmo valor de imagens na página, mas apenas altere as imagens)

```
 <?php
$url    = "http://hebbohotel.com.br/swf/gamedata/hebbo_texts.txt?9761831";
$data   = file_get_contents($url);

$newlines   = array("\n" ,"\r", "\r\n", ">", "<", "/");
$content    = str_replace($newlines, "", html_entity_decode($data));

$statusHtml = '/badge_desc_(.+?)=/';
preg_match_all($statusHtml, $content, $statusRaw);

$badges     = implode("-", $statusRaw[0]);
$badgeVar   = explode("=-badge_desc_", $badges);
$badgeVar2  = str_replace("=", "", $badgeVar);
$badgeVar3  = str_replace("badge_desc_", "", $badgeVar2);
$number     = count($badgeVar3);

$i = 1;
$e = 24;


while ($i <= $e)
{
    $number     = $number - 1;
    $imageUrl   = "http://hebbohotel.com.br/swf/c_images/album1584/" . $badgeVar3[$number] . ".gif";
echo '<div class="emblema" style="background:url(' . $imageUrl . ') no-repeat center,  #E7E7E7;"></div>'; // changed this echo to display the image.
    $i++;
}

?>
```

Quero que quando aperte um botão, ele busque as próximas imagens, link do php hospedado: http://rafagarcia.pe.hu/hebbo.php

Answer (score 0):

Em uma rápida olhada em seu código, sua pergunta pode ter duas respostas:

1 - Observei que foi limitado para 24 iterações:

```
$i = 1;
$e = 24;

while ($i <= $e)
```

Se deixar a variável $e dinâmica de interatividade por clique:

```
$i = 1;
$e = 24;
// aqui você entra com incremento de variável
$maisClique = ((isset($_GET['cliquei']) and !empty($_GET['cliquei']))?$_GET['cliquei']:false);

if(isset($maisClique) and !empty($maisClique)){
    $e += $maisClique;
}
while...
```

2 - Se você quer substituir as 24 imagens por novas imagens de seu servidor, aí o índice do array é que vai ser alterado:

```
// aqui você entra com incremento de variável
$maisClique = ((isset($_GET['cliquei']) and !empty($_GET['cliquei']))?$_GET['cliquei']:false);

// aqui você altera a porção dos elementos do array: 24, 48, 72, 96...
$number     = ((isset($maisClique) and !empty($maisClique))?($number - $maisClique):$number);

while ($i <= $e){
    $number = $number - 1;
    $imageUrl   = "http://hebbohotel.com.br/swf/c_images/album1584/" .$badgeVar3[$number] . ".gif";
    echo '<div class="emblema" style="background:url(' . $imageUrl . ') no-repeat center,  #E7E7E7;"></div>'; // changed this echo to display the image.
    $i++;
}
```

Porém este modelo pede que vc execute a página em cada clique, se quer fazer sem reload da página precisa incrementar um ajax, ou jquery.

Observação: ( $number - 1 ) refere a decremento do índice da matriz, se ao curso de 24 iterações o índice zerar, ou esvaziar-se, será retornado um valor nullo para cada imagem, o mais comum é observar incremento, ( $number + 1 ), no índice da matriz!

Observação 2: $number é o total de indices:

```
$number     = count($badgeVar3);
```

Como está, você ordenou ao código trazer os últimos 24 elementos na ordem inversa!

Comment: Não havia aberto a página em questão apenas observei seu código... Agora enviei o o botão com as prévias verificações em php para atualização dinâmica, pode ser para a variável $e ou para a variável $number, você escolhe!

Answer (score 0):

Bem, após ver a página que percebi ainda não haver o botão, então segue aí:

```
    echo '<div class="emblema" style="background:url(' . $imageUrl . ') no-repeat center,  #E7E7E7;"></div>'; // changed this echo to display the image.
    $i++;
}
// aqui você define o valor $cliques que será calculado em $number para alterações da matriz
if(isset($_GET['cliquei']) and !empty($_GET['cliquei'])){
    $cliques = $_GET['cliquei'] + 24;
}else{
    $cliques = 24;
}
// aqui encerra o php e entra o botão cliquei
?>
<input type="button" onclick="window.location.replace('http://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?cliquei=".$cliques ?>')" value="cliquei" />

//--- fim
```

Acredito ser este o caminho para sua matriz atualizar!

Comment: Olá, olhe oque está acontecendo: http://rafagarcia.pe.hu/hebbo2.php

Comment: pode me ajudar?